# C# WinForms Rich Editor with Right-to-Left Unicode Support

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode, localization, richtext

Are there any rich editors for WinForms that support right-to-left and can export to HTML?

The standard RichTextBox cannot export to HTML (Is there an RTF to HTML converter?)

DevExpress's XtraRichEdit doesn't support right-to-left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NRTFTree - A class library for RTF processing in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/nrtftree.aspx) for managing Rich Text

**Note:** NRtfTree is NOT a library to convert RTF to HTML, but there's an example on achieving this using NRtfTree in one of the demo source files.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at following link:

- [An extended RichTextBox to save and load "HTML lite" files](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/htmlrichtextbox.aspx)